# Create leads or contacts from marketing cloud with landing pages smart capture

Tags: marketing-cloud, contact, leads, landing-page, hidden-fields

Can anyone guide me on how can we generate leads or contacts in Salesforce through a smartcapture form with hidden fields like record type? I only have landing pages in web studio.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your Marketing Cloud and Sales Cloud are integrated, you will need to have the form post back to another landing page/microsite page within email studio and have that page perform the AMPScript call below.

https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_functions_for_use_with_salesforcecom/createsalesforceobject/

%%[ var @id
set @id=CreateSalesforceObject("lead", 2, "FirstName", "Chris", "LastName", "Cruz")
]%%